# Typescript assining value from input type number

Tags: javascript, typescript

i'm making a calculator
when i assign value from input type as given

```
 <input type="number" id="intype">
```

it generate an error
[img is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOEpA.jpg)

Comment: what is your error?

Answer (score 0):

**Mention it as unknown like below**

```
a = document.getElementById('intype').value as unknown
```

**OR**

**try to parse input**

```
a=parseInt(document.getElementById('intype').value)
```

Since `document.getElementById('intype').value` will return string and you are storing it in number you need to parse it.

Comment: Type = number input do return a number, it is just a compiler error. No need to parse, just tell the compiler it is as unknown.

Comment: @Adrian Yes true

Answer (score 0):

Tell the compiler it is not a string

a = document.getElementById('intype').value as unknown